# PDF: Print Twice To Get Rid of Unwanted Part

Tags: pdf, printing

Similar questions has been asked but I still cannot get it exactly.

I have a PDF document with unwanted text at the bottom. Exactly the same text box at the exact location at each page. (Say the paper size 6in x 10in, and say the unwanted part occupies the bottom 0.5 in.)

(Yes, I can delete the text box at each page but the document is over 1.000 pages long.)

If I crop the pages, the cropped part is still part of the PDF. (That someone can re-crop and the text boxes will reappear.)

Is it possible to print (as .PDF) say the 6in x 9.5in portion of each page to a 6in x 10in page?

Comment: If the top and side margins are wide enough you may be able to scale it when printing, so that the bottom disappears but top and sides stay on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done easily with [Ricoh's Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info).

1. Create a new profile with a file printer channel (if you want to create PDF documents) or a printer channel (if you want to print on paper).
2. Go to the Get More Editor and draw a rectangle (for example white one with white border). (watch this video to see where the Get More Editor is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03RbCbBkAL8&index=5&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2 )
3. In the properties (right side) of the rectangle say that the page range is All pages.
4. click Send & Close and you have your pdf.